# odoo 8 domain variable from other class

Tags: python, list, odoo, odoo-8

I have 2 classes, the first one containing a function with a list created in it.

```
class the_first_class(models.Model)
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'

    def first_function(self):
         list1 = []
```

A second class, containing a field where a want to specify a domain based on the list created in "first_function" of "the_first_class". Like following:

```
class second_class(models.Model)
     _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

     field1 = fields.Many2one('product.product', domain=[('id','in',list1)])
```

Is there a way I can call the "list1" like this? Or maybe specify the domain based on a function? And then call the variable "list1" inside the function like:

```
self.env['mrp.bom'].list1
```

The full code:

```
class bom_excl_list(models.Model):
_inherit = 'mrp.bom'

excl_list = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='product.template')

def methodA(self):   
    self.test = [17,18]

@api.onchange('bom_line_ids', 'excl_list') 
def get_excl_list(self):

     print self.excl_list
     list1 = []
     for i in self.excl_list:
         list1.append(i.id)

     list2 = []
     for j in self.bom_line_ids.product_id:
         list2.append(j.id)


class bom_filtered_products(models.Model):

_inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'  

def methodB(self):
    A = bom_excl_list()
    A.methodA()
    print "List", A.test
    return [('id','=',A.test)]

filtered_products = fields.Many2one('product.product', domain=methodB)
```

views.xml:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_bom_form">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.form</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@string='Components']/field[@name='bom_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
               <field name="filtered_products"/>
            </xpath>  
            <xpath expr="//page[@string='Properties']/group" position="after">
                <group>
                    <!-- <field name="excl_list" widget="many2many_checkboxes"/>  -->
                    <field name="excl_list"/>
                </group>
            </xpath>    
        </field>            
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per python approach you can do it by following sample code

```
class Class_A():
    def methodA(self):
        self.myList = []

class Class_B():
    def methodB(self):
        A = Class_A()
        A.methodA()
        print "Wow! You got your list here ->", A.myList
```

You can also declare a list in **init**() method if you don't want to call method of Class_A.
As per my knowledge it also works for Odoo8.

Comment: Hi when I execute this code I get the following error:
Error details: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'methodA'" while parsing /root/git/odoo/modules/project1/views.xml:634, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_bom_form">
....

Comment: My code is the same as the one you listed above, with the only exception that the first class (Class_A) inhertits from 'mrp.bom' and the second class (Class_B) from 'mrp.bom.line'

I use the views.xml file to display other fields I declared in the first class. But this worked before the only thing I added was the new method (methodA) and the list

Answer (score 0):

Your full code is look like this after some changes...

```
class bom_excl_list(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'

    excl_list = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='product.template')

    def methodA(self):
        print "***methodA is Calling***"    
        test = [17,18]
        return test


    @api.onchange('bom_line_ids', 'excl_list') 
    def get_excl_list(self):
        print self.excl_list
        list1 = []
        for i in self.excl_list:
            list1.append(i.id)

        list2 = []
        for j in self.bom_line_ids.product_id:
            list2.append(j.id)


class bom_filtered_products(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'  

    def methodB(self):
        bom = self.env['mrp.bom']
        print "You get your list here------------>>>>>", bom.methodA()
        #A = bom_excl_list()
        #A.methodA()
        #print "List", A.test
        #return [('id','=',A.test)]
        return [('id','=',bom.methodA())]

    filtered_products = fields.Many2one('product.product', domain=methodB)
```